JMeter Save response to a file - naming convention
Is there a possible way of dynamically naming the files on 'Save response to a file' as the request loops?
I knew about JMeter's note of not using thread related variables, but is there a work-around for this?
I would really appreciate your thoughts.
Thanks xx

You can use whatever JMeter Functions or Variables you want as the filename prefix.
For example if you configure Save Responses to a file listener like this:

Here is the text version of the prefix:
iteration-${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}-thread-${__threadNum}-response.txt

You will get the following files:
iteration-1-thread-1-response.txt
iteration-1-thread-2-response.txt
iteration-2-thread-1-response.txt
iteration-2-thread-2-response.txt
etc.

More information: A Guide to the JMeter File Upload/Download Feature
